# how can i toggle multiple <View> data react native

Tags: react-native

I want to toggle multiple data. i tried it but not succeeded .

```
render() {
    return(
     <ScrollView style={styles.drawer}>
       <View style={styles.content} key={1}>
          <ListView
                    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                    renderRow={(data) =>
                        <View>
                            <Text style={styles.navMenuTop} onPress={this.handlePressTopCat.bind(this)}> 
                                {'› '+data.Name}
                            </Text>

                             {data.SubItems.map((b,Index) =>
                              <View style={{height:this.state.SubHeight}}>
                                   <Text style={styles.navMenu} onPress={this.handlePressCatid.bind(this,b.cPath)}> {'» '+b.Name}</Text>


                               </View> 
                                )}
                        </View>
                        }
           />

        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

how can i toggle multiple div. SubItems can be toggle when clicked on navMenuTop. it should be working like menu.

Comment: Try SectionList https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist.html

Comment: i can't understand sectionlist, how it can be working like menu

Comment: If there is 2 level hierarchy then we can show submenu based on parent click. We can store parent menu expand flag and based on that show child menu.

Answer (score 0):

```
            import React, { Component } from 'react';
            import { Container, Header, Content, Card, CardItem, Body, Text,Button } from 'native-base';
            import _isEqual from 'lodash/isEqual';
            import _map from 'lodash/map';
            export default class CardExample extends Component {
              constructor(props) {
                super();
                this.state = {
                  previousState: '',
                  cardData: [1,2,3,4,5],
                };
              }
               componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
                if (!_isEqual(this.state.previousState, nextState.previousState)) {
                  this.setState({ [this.state.previousState]: false});
                }

              }

              open(key){
                this.setState({ [key]: !this.state[key],previousState:key});
              }
              render() {
                return (
                  <Container>
                    <Header />
                    <Content>
                      {
                       _map(this.state.cardData,(data,key)=>{
                        return (
                          <Card>
                            <CardItem header>
                              <Text>Card {key} header</Text>
                            </CardItem>
                            {
                              this.state[`open_${key}`] ? 
                                <CardItem>
                                  <Body>
                                    <Text>
                                      This is cardItem {key} Body element
                                    </Text>
                                  </Body>
                                </CardItem>

                              : null
                            }
                            <CardItem footer>
                              <Button onPress={()=>this.open(`open_${key}`)}><Text>open {key}</Text></Button>
                            </CardItem>
                         </Card>
                          )
                       })
                      }
                    </Content>
                  </Container>
                );
              }
            }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @johan I am new to stackoverflow. So I don't know how to post in a proper way. Sorry for that.